# ¿Como iterar en un dataframe por un numero determinado de filas?

Tags: python, array, pandas, numpy, ciencia-de-datos

tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.date_range('20180101', periods=300)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(300, 5), index=data,
              columns=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
```

quiero iterar cada dos filas, es decir tomar el valor de cada dos filas para luego hacer algo con ellas, alguna forma con pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introducción

En Pandas iterar no suele ser la mejor solución. La mayoría de las veces que quieres iterar es porque quieres ir realizando algún tipo de cálculo con los contenidos de las filas. Pandas implementa gran cantidad de cálculos "vectorizados", que significa que los efectúa en una sola línea de código, teniendo en cuenta muchas filas a la vez, sin que tengas que implementar tú bucle alguno (es Pandas quien internamente hace las iteraciones, generalmente delegando en numpy y en código nativo en C, mucho más rápido y eficiente que hacerlo tú en Python).

Por ejemplo, para obtener la suma de la columna "volume" del dataframe `df`, podrías pensar en iterar por todas las filas e ir obteniendo el valor de esa columna para ir acumulándola, algo así:

```
suma = 0
for v in df.volume
    suma += v
```

Pero es mucho más corto y eficiente:

```
suma = df.volume.sum()
```

No digamos ya si quisieras calcular el valor promedio de *todas* las columnas. La solución con un bucle requeriría mantener una variable "acumulador" para cada columna, probablemente el uso de `df.iterrows()`, etc. mientras que la solución pandas es simplemente `df.mean()`.

Si en lugar de querer actuar por todas las filas quieres solo un subconjunto de ellas, puedes aplicar `df.loc` o `df.iloc` y poner en una expresión entre corchetes el rango de valores del index (para el primer caso) o de números de fila (para el segundo caso).

Por ejemplo, ya que en tu caso el index es de tipo `datetime`, puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente para operar sólo con los datos correspondientes a enero:

```
df.loc["2018-01":"2018-02"]
```

y sobre esa selección hacer cualquier operación, como `.sum()`, `.mean()`, etc.

O actuar sólo sobre las 50 primeras filas con:

```
df.iloc[0:50]
```

### En tu caso

Tú pides tomar el valor cada dos filas. A `.iloc[]` le pasas un *slice* python normal, por lo que puedes usar la sintaxis `[inicio:fin:paso]` y poner cualquier valor deseado en el paso. Así, por ejemplo, lo siguiente seleccionaría todas las filas pares:

```
df.iloc[::2]
```

y lo siguiente todas las impares:

```
df.iloc[1::2]
```

Ejemplo:

```
>>> print(df.iloc[::2].agg(["count", "mean"]))
             open        high         low       close      volume
count  150.000000  150.000000  150.000000  150.000000  150.000000
mean    -0.248744   -0.086711    0.021593    0.024451    0.157441
```

Answer (score 1):

La forma más elemental es iterar mediante un indice numérico de a 2 pasos e ir haciendo  "slices" (recortes) sobre el `dataframe` por este indice numérico:

```
for i in range(0, len(df), 2):
  row1 = df[i:i+1]
  row2 = df[i+1:i+2]
```

En `row1` y `row2` obtienes un `DataFrame` con una sola fila correspondiente a la primera y segunda de cada iteración. Otra forma más sencilla, pero obteniendo una `Serie` es usar `iloc()`

```
for i in range(0, len(df), 2):
  row1 = df.iloc[i]
  row2 = df.iloc[i+1]
```

Obviamente, estas soluciones asumen un total de filas pares.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que creo que puedes hacer es un while o un for. por ejemplo:

```
a=0

while(True):
   while(a<2):
     data = pd.date_range('20180101', periods=300)
     df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(300, 5), index=data,
              columns=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])

     a = 0
     ////hacer lo que tengas pensado despues
```

Luego automaticamente volvera al while